# QGIS expression to check if a an attribute value of a feature exist in another attribute column

Tags: qgis, expression, select-by-expression

I have a shapefile with two fields 'Name' and 'CountyFacilityID'. I would like to create an expression to select all features where Name exists in the CountyFacilityID column for any of the features.

I tried `array_contains( "CountyFACILITYID" ,  "NAME" )` but it didn't work as it is not considering FacilityID as an array

[image]

Comment: Naive idea here: Shouldn't `"CountyFACILITYID" IN "NAME"` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to aggregate the values of the other column first. For example like this:

`array_contains( array_agg( "CountyFACILITYID" ), "Name" )`

Answer (score 0):

What about just

```
"Name" = "CountyFacilityID"
```

Comment: That will only check for the CountyFacilityID of that feature. I want to check for all features, and if Name exist for any of the feature as CountyFacilityID, I want it to be selected.